# Rails partial table validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a form that I'm trying to create which is broken up into sections. Each section saves a little bit of info to that table and then moves on to the next page.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to validate the data for each section in the model.  I was to use something like validates_presence_of, but that expects all of the data that is being validated will be available upon saving... In my case, the entire table won't be filled out until they're done going through each section.

What's the best way to do this if there is a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make validations conditional with the `:if` or `:unless` options. If you add a "step" column to your table you can use this to validate the model along the way.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name # step 1
  validates_presence_of :category_id, :if => Proc.new { |i| i.step >= 2 } # step 2
  validates_presence_of :description, :if => Proc.new { |i| i.step >= 3 } # step 3
end
```

You can then increment the step count each time in your controller.

```
def update
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @item.step += 1
  if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
    # ...
  end
end
```

You may also want to consider using a [state machine](http://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/tree/master).

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice grouped_validations gem out there that facilitates validating limited groups of model attributes at a time.  No need for state tracking as above.

See the [overview docs on github](https://github.com/adzap/grouped_validations).